# Compute the following surface integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

Compute $\int_S \mathbf{F}\cdot d \mathbf{S}$ where $\mathbf{F}(x, y, z) = (x, y, z)$ and S is given by
$$g(u,v) = \begin{pmatrix} u-v \\ u + v \\ uv \end{pmatrix}$$
when $0 \le u \le 1, 0 \le v \le 2$.

We can define the surface integral of F over S by
$$\int _d \mathbf{F}(g(u,v)) \cdot \left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial u}(u,v)\space  \times \space \frac{\partial g}{\partial v}(u,v)  \right)dudv$$

We can calculate the following as $$\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial u}(u,v)\space  \times \space \frac{\partial g}{\partial v}(u,v)  \right)= (u-v, -u-v, 2)$$

However I'm unsure on how to proceed from here as $\mathbf{F}(x,y,z)$ throws me off, so I'd really appreciate some guidance from the community!

Comment: Any questions or comments related to my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parametrized surface is $g(u ,v) = (u-v, u + v, uv), 0 \le u \le 1, 0 \le v \le 2$

The vector field $\vec F = (x, y, z)$

So, $ \vec F(g(u, v)) = (u-v, u+v, uv)$

As you obtained, $g_u \times g_v = (u-v, -u-v, 2)$

$ \big[$ Note that the orientation of the surface is not given so it could either be $g_u \times g_v$ or $g_v \times g_u \big]$

Then, $\vec F(g(u, v)) \cdot (g_u \times g_v) = - 2uv$

So the surface integral is,

$ \displaystyle \iint_D \vec F(g(u, v)) \cdot (g_u \times g_v) ~ du ~ dv = \int_0^2 \int_0^1 - 2uv ~ du ~ dv$

$ = - 2$